# what is the difference between cms page link and cms static block. Catalog product link and catalog category link

Tags: magento2, catalog, cms, cms-block, cms-pages

I know about catalog new product list, and how to make them show on the home page using the widget. But am having a hard time understanding the difference between cms page link and cms static block. Catalog product link and catalog category link.  And how to use them.

Answer (score 4):

- CMS page: A page which is dynamic and editable (not the category page and product page) such as informative pages.
  (Content > Pages)
- CMS block: It includes any dynamic content of your page, which can be placed on any CMS or other pages.
  (Content > Blocks)
- Catalog Category: You can manage/create categories/sub categories from here.
- Catalog Product: You can manage/create products from here.

Answer (score 1):

The diffrence are specify like this.

1. CMS page : it means it new page like about-us page and privacy-policy page etc. You can create and manage it from admin.
2. CMS Block : means some part of code which you can create and manage from admin.
3. Calatog Product Link : it means the URL of any particular product page.
4. Catalog Category Link : It means the URL of any particular category page.

Comment: how do i add text inline or beside an image static block

Answer (score 0):

**CMS Page link:** A page this includes an extra page in your store (other than the category and the product page) such as About us page, Terms and conditions etc.

**CMS Static Block:** A Static block, on the other hand, includes any content on your page, this is found on the home page, category page or product page. An example of static blocks, is footer links, banner images and side banners.

**Calatog Product Link:** URL of any particular product page.

**Catalog Category Link:** URL of any particular category page.

Hope this will clear your query.

Comment: How do i create a cms static block showing image and text (inline or beside it)  with a link to a product or  category